# The code within my def function won't run. No error message at all; how can I make it work?

Tags: python-3.x

def variables() exists so that the program will reset when the user chooses to start a new game, or at least this is my intention. However, nothing is printed to the shell when I try to initially run the program. People seem to use this sort of def variables() operator(?) to reset programs, at least this is how I interpreted it upon researching it. What can be done to make the program run properly?

EDIT: If I'm completely missing the purpose of what def is supposed to do, please let me know. Every explanation I see online is unclear to me.

```
import random
def variables():
    y = 0
    x = 0
    i = 1
    a_random = random.randrange(-3,3,1)
    b_random = random.randrange(-3,3,1)

    while i > 0:


        question = (input("You can go up, down, left, and right. Which do you choose? "));

        if question in ["up"]:
            y = y + 1
            print("You've moved up one unit!")
            print("Your position is now (", x, ",", y, ")")


        if question in ["down"]:
            y = y - 1
            print("You've moved down one unit!")
            print("Your position is now (", x, ",", y, ")")


        if question in ["right"]:
            x = x + 1
            print("You've moved right one unit!")
            print("Your position is now (", x, ",", y, ")")


        if question in ["left"]:
            x = x - 1
            print("You've moved left one unit!")
            print("Your position is now (", x, ",", y, ")")


        if (x == a_random) and (y == b_random):
            print("You've found the treasure!")
            repeat = (input("Play again? "))
            if repeat in ["yes"]:
                variables()
            if repeat in ["no"]:
                i = -1
                print("Game over.")

        if question in ["cheats"]:
            print("The treasure is located at (", a_random, ", ", b_random, ").")
```

Comment: `def` defines a function and gives it a name... A function is a series of commands that can be executed by using the name. You're defining the function but not actually executing it. A simple `variables()` at the end of the file (not indented) should work. A function also has its own variable scope (Where in code a variable can be "seen" from). Have a read of this http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/

Answer (score 2):

Is this the full program?  You aren't actually executing the variables() function anywhere.  You probably want:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    variables()
```

That said, I'd revisit some texts on basic Python program structure before moving further.